# can't make ViewPager and ScrollView work together

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-touch-event

I have custom custom ViewPager that have fragments with ScrollView. I need to disable ViewPager in some cases, so I implemented it in onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent methods:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private static final String TAG = NonSwipeableViewPager.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private float initialX;

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        isEnabled = false;
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        isEnabled = false;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: move");
                float currentX = ev.getX();

                // disable right swipe
                if (initialX - currentX < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent: down");
                initialX = ev.getX();                
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent: move");
            }
        }
        if (isEnabled) {
            return onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }
}
```

ScrollView works fine as long as isEnabled is false. But when its true, ScrollView become disabled and all touch events affect only ViewPager.

I tried to distinguish between vertical and horizontal move events in onInterceptTouchEvent but log looks like:

```
onInterceptTouchEvent: down
onTouchEvent: move
onTouchEvent: move
onTouchEvent: move
...
```

So I can't do it in onInterceptTouchEvent and I can't reach ScrollView from OnTouchEvent.

What I can do to make ScrollView and ViewPager work together when ViewPager is enabled?

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"            
            android:layout_below="@id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.vlad.vocabimprover.testex.NonSwipeableViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Remember that Java code must be in a class.

Comment: Then you should include it in your code here.

Comment: Its not needed. There is enough code to explain my problem

Comment: You can choose to ignore my request. Then I will choose to spend my time helping someone else.

Comment: I added class code. Ask whatever you want

Comment: Could you show your XML?

Comment: @Sufian xml was added.

Comment: The layout seems okay. Why do you need to disable `ViewPager`? Maybe you're looking to decrease its sensitivity only?

Comment: I disable it after every fragment change and enable only if something happens - e.g., button click. Maybe there is a way to disable it without overriding OnTouchEvent?

Comment: @Vlad you didn't answer why you need to disable it?